# How to remove everything from free hard disk space permanently and make it unrecoverable

Tags: 16.04, hard-drive, ssd, cleanup

I recently installed Ubuntu on my Windows 7 machine and I have used a few tools in the past that recover data from SSD even after everything has been erased. I was wondering if there is a way to clean the HDD in a way that any data from Windows 7 cannot be recovered. So I have 200GB on sda1 and I basically want to make sure that from the available 200GB nothing is recoverable.

Comment: Possible answer: http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/90942/how-to-make-data-in-hard-disk-unrecoverable-on-linux

Comment: @PatrickNegus :( I guess that would be the last resort if i dont find anything.

Comment: @NickDiv It's a fun last resort, though :)

Comment: @PatrickNegus For now I used the blkdiscard as suggested by AlexP and also hdparm from a few articles I read on 'Secure Erase SSD' after that I ran a few recovery tools on the machine and some of the data was still there but most of it was gone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
sudo dd if=/dev/zero bs=1M of=/dev/sda1
```

Be *sure* that you will never want anything back from `sda1`, because everything will be gone forever. On my system this works at about 100 megabytes per second, so 200 gigabytes will take about 2000 seconds or some 40 minutes.

If `sda1` is a SSD then this is both overkill and useless at the same time; it's overkill because a `sudo blkdiscard /dev/sda1` is very very much faster, and useless because SSDs do not overwrite physical blocks. There is no absolutely safe way to delete data off a SSD if your adversary is the Cheka; however, if your adversary is the Cheka with the mighty power of the Soviet State behind it then you have greater and more urgent problems than wiping data off disks.

Comment: Haha, great answer.. :) But yes its SSD. I should probably update the question

Comment: Just use `blkdiscard`. It is good enough for any reasonable use case (except gainst allmighty state agencies).

Comment: Cool, thanks. Ran the command. It was pretty quick. I mean not even a second.. Thanks for the answer.